# How to avoid shutter sound struggling during capturing still image with `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm capturing image with `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`. All done fine. But I tried to navigate into new view controller, the shuttering sound struggles. Any workaround to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set output to **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput** (not AVCaptureStillImageOutput) and capture single frame from the video output.

Comment: any quality considerations to know when using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?